# probabilistic analysis of a recursive code

Tags: probability, discrete-mathematics, permutations, recurrence-relations

Consider this algorithm that comes from Jeff Erickson algorithm text book and try to shuffle elements of given array:

```
    Shuffle(A[1...n])
    if n=1
      return
     j=1
     k=n
     while j<=k
      with probability 1/2
        swap A[k] with A[j]
        k=k-1
      else
        j=j+1
  Shuffle(A[1 .. k])
  Shuffle(A[ j .. n])
```

You can see the image of the question in the book:
[image]
Now I should show that the probability of generating each permutation of $n!$ permutations in the Shuffle algorithm, is $\frac{1}{n!}$.

**My attempt**

I think we should achieve something like
$$\frac{1}{\binom{n}{k}}\times\frac{1}{k!}\times\frac{1}{n!}=\frac{1}{n!}$$
But how we can achieve above formula, I get stuck.

Comment: which page of the book (and edition)?

Comment: Does this algo even generate $n!$ permutations?

Comment: You can see the book at https://jeffe.cs.illinois.edu/teaching/algorithms/notes/01-random.pdf